# Looking for Suitable Fonts for Page Header and Footer

Tags: font-recommendation

I am looking for fonts that are easy to read and look elegant in small sizes. (Even though “elegant” is in the eye of the beholder.) Both free and paid suggestions are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fit's the entire concep but I'd go for sans serif like

- [Thesans](http://www.lucasfonts.com/fonts/thesans/) great and has a wonderful free all-caps version
- [ITC Avant Garde](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/) - very elegant and
- [Raleway](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/raleway) - one of the best free fonts out there

Now if you have to go for Serif or slab serif:

- [Fanwood](https://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/fanwood) - free
- [Caecilia](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/pmn-caecilia/) - very elegant
- Good old [Baskerville](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/baskerville/)
- [Miller](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/fontbureau/miller/)